# Why don't most life forms show uniqueness in progeny?

Tags: reproduction, genomes

I guess everyone must have observed this. Dogs, cats, and most of all insects (including mosquitoes) appear more or less the same.

Why is there so little variation in their offspring, unlike humans, where you rarely find two humans showing even a little resemblence.

Is it the large size of the human genome that allows infinite combination of traits? (seems unlikely, as even small flies like *drosophila melanogaster* have somewhat large genomes, but show very little variation).

Comment: @iayork I'd searched but couldn't find. Thanks.